# Is the tense in “people wonder how they ever lived without them” correct?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is the following sentence grammatically wrong?

> Organic pulses are so popular today that many people wonder how they ever lived without them.

I think it is not incorrect but the solution in my book says **how they ever lived without them** is wrongly used, instead it should be used in present tense.

Comment: It's not wrong; it's fine. What book are you using?

Comment: If by "should be used in present tense" you mean the text should read *...people wonder how they ever **live** without them*, you're completely mistaken. Imho that's not even ***valid***, let alone "preferable".

Comment: People wonder how they managed to live (in the past) before such things were available.

Comment: Either the book is wrong or you read it wrongly - can you type or give a link to the exact text?

Comment: This book has been causing confusion for a while apparently: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/406477/80039 I’ve also found it here with the incorrect answer: https://www.examcompetition.com/forum/32796/in-the-following-question-some-part-of-the-sentenc

Comment: I’ve also found this explanation of  why the exam thinks it needs correction *“In 3rd part of sentence “have” should be used after “they”. “Had” should not be used as it will give the sense that people could not live without pulses but now people can live without pulses.”* at https://www.sscadda.com/important-english-questions-for-ssc-cgl21

Comment: Typical non-native EFL textbook. Put anything in a book and some school will swear it's gospel. And make you believe it.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly okay. My guess is that your book is wrong.